# 100 plots in 1 multi page pdf in R

Tags: r, gplots

I have R script which creates 100 plots.
How to create 1 single PDF with 50 pages?
2 plots on each page.I tried using
`par(mfrow=(50,2))`
but its giving Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Answer (score 5):

you want 2 plots per page, so you need `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`. R will automatically switch to the next page if you ask it to plot more than 2 plots.

```
pdf("myoutput.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
for (i in 1:100) {
  plot(runif(10)
}
```

should produce a 50 pages pdf, with 2 plots per page.

Comment: Thanks @xraynaud. Its working. You made my day!